# Problems in Subscription of global event in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following JavaScript Code, I have some queries on these lines,

1. what does this  lines `.events.slice (-1)[0][0]` means?
2. and `nodes_params += "&ns=" + GLOBAL_EVENT + "," + start_from + ",-,-";` this lines as well?
3. What does the *Subscription of the global events* means?

The whole code is too big, but I can post some of the parts of the code, in case it is not understable.

```
// Subscribe to the global events
    var start_from = "0";
    if (nodes[GLOBAL_EVENT].events && nodes[GLOBAL_EVENT].events.length > 0) {
        start_from = nodes[GLOBAL_EVENT].events.slice(-1)[0][0];
    }
    nodes_params += "&ns=" + GLOBAL_EVENT + "," + start_from + ",-,-";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 - `events` is on array and `events.slice(-1)` returns the last element in this array, witch seems to be an multidimensional array itself ,and [0][0] returns the first element in the first array.

2 - its a simple string concatenation, += mean appending to the existing variable instead of replacing it

3 - can't say for sure, it depends on what the other codes are